# How to list all the installed packages and their version with Cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is there a simple command / option that lets you do that? I could use `grep` but I wonder if there is a builtin option?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

We can simply do:

```
cabal list --installed
```

Comment: There is also `ghc-pkg list`.