# Nix shell: How to list the installed Haskell package versions

Tags: haskell, nix

As a *non-nix'er* I installed the newest version of https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform. I think working in this nix-shell is a nice experience.

Now I want to know which Haskell packages in which versions are installed and used in this shell. After some googling I found a *nix-env* command in the following form:

`nix-env -f '<nixpkgs>' -qaPA haskellPackages|grep reflex-dom`

This command gives me the version of reflex-dom as *reflex-dom-0.3*. But I know from [here](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-dom/blob/develop/reflex-dom/default.nix) that in my nix shell I use the newest version *0.4* of reflex-dom. So I assume the above command just lists the available Hackage packages.

What is the correct *nix-env -q* command to get only the installed Haskell packages and its versions?.

(I played with the --installed option, however I never got something back)

Comment: Not sure why question should be any different for Nix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953396/how-to-list-the-installed-packages-in-cabal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to `nix-store -q --references $out` after you entered the shell. This will, however, mix both haskell and non-haskell dependencies in output.

This is a complete example with filter applied:

`$ nix-store -q --references $out \
    | while read p; do du -a $p | grep -q ghc && echo $p; done`

Comment: From your command `nix-store -q --references $out` I get a result of 11 lines. One very interesting line is `/nix/store/34h4mj588w6q0q18izpxrc4wc0wqbfl4-ghc-8.0.2-with-packages`, an other interesting line is `/nix/store/knbj6a7b3ra8zawy1jmlvahmr8x7rxnd-ghcjs-0.2.0-with-packages`. My interest is to know what is exactly behind _with-packages_. What are all these packages and their versions?

Comment: try to run `nix-store -q --references ` for ghc-with-packages line

Comment: Yes, the command `nix-store -q --references /nix/store/34h4mj588w6q0q18izpxrc4wc0wqbfl4-ghc-8.0.2-with-packages` generates an interesting list. Thanks!